# How do I create a Wiki using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wiki

I was recently given a task to create a blog using Ruby on Rails. So I found a [very helpful guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), which was very helpful for the blog. However, there seems to be a short supply of good Ruby-on-Rails guides on creating a wiki that is, up to date, makes sense and accurate.

Comment: Maybe you should create your own Rails wiki and document your experience :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check existing gems for wikis: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps

There are 3 rails-based wikis.

The most active is https://github.com/alno/irwi.

Other two, https://github.com/queso/signal-wiki and https://github.com/AndyMoreland/kii, was not updated for years, but still you can try to look through sources to get the base idea

Comment: Is there not a way to do it without using a plugin for rails?